# Advanced Query Syntax - how to query only files in current directory only?

Tags: windows, windows-search, advanced-query-syntax

Is it possible to search within current directory only (i.e. to specify depth = 0 or relative path, without changing the search settings in the toolbar)?

I tried multiple queries like: `./path` or `-filename:*`, but nothing has excluded the child files in subfolders.

Comment: I don't know of any. Your best bet would be a `Shift+Right-click` in the folder background and launching **PowerShell**, then `gci` with either a simple filter or piped to `Where-Object` with your search criteria.

Comment: @KeithMiller Thanks, I can not use PowerShell, my target usecase of AQS is https://superuser.com/questions/1517945 . Do I understand correctly relative paths to cwd are not supported by AQS at all? Do you know any other solution how to check for a file directry in cwd for the context-menu usecase?

Comment: What is **cwd**?

Comment: Use `foldername:folder` or `in:folder`

Comment: @KeithMiller cwd = current working directory, @DavidPostill this does not work, as it searches the `folder` also in child directories, that is the question about.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to achieve what you want through the UI. Also, regarding your larger context menu question, I don't think there is any trick of the shell that will get you there. For the functionality you describe, I think you'd need to code a full-fledged shell extension.